# Selenium Manager is unable to automatically download chromedriver from the JSON endpoint

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to learn about Selenium but I can't manage to even write a basic script.

The version of Chrome I have installed is 117.0.5938.150. I read that Selenium will automatically download the appropriate chromedriver for versions after 114, but its not working for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html")

driver.quit()
```

This is the error displayed by vscode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 98, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 144, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.        
{'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.149/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (os error 10060)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}     


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m:\.socials\CS Lang. n Technologies\Python\email_tracker_project\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

What should I do? I would prefer some automatic solution instead of downloading chromedriver myself cuz I can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest Selenium to get Selenium Manager working. They did an update last couple couple minor versions (?) that fixed the driver download location.